# phpDoc for object's properties

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc, bitrix

I've got file template.php, that is included in `CBitrixComponentTemplate`'s method.
`CBitrixComponentTemplate` has property `$this->__component`, that is dynamicly filled with object `EtmOrderAdd`. `EtmOrderAdd` has property `objValidator`.

Now, when I am writing the file `template.php`, I need all these properties to be understood by `phpDoc`.
Here's the picture, illustrating my idea :

[image]

How should I write it?

Comment: `@property` only works when used in PHPDoc for THAT class -- it will not work the way you are trying to use it. Since I'm not familiar with Bitrix at all, my only suggestion right now would be to introduce intermediate variable and use it instead (and for such case ordinary `@var` will work)

Answer (score 3):

Bitrix has almost no phpDoc for internal methods and functions. Also it has a plenty of legacy code, that won't show correctly with PhpStorm's code completion.

However, there are several things you can try to improve the situation:

- Add [bxApiDocs](https://github.com/matiaspub/bxApiDocs) files as an *External Library* to PhpStorm.
  This will add autocomplete for the internal *bitrix* methods
- It seems like you've defined custom component class since `$template->__component` usually contains `CBitrixComponent` object that doesn't have `objValidator` property. So you need to add `@property` inside your `class.php` file of your component.